# Update a Bokeh Span with an interact element in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I am trying to make a span in bokeh using jupyter widgets.

```
from ipywidgets import interact

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

from bokeh.sampledata.daylight import daylight_warsaw_2013
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Span
output_notebook()
p = figure()

x_axis = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.001)
# Mean = 0, SD = 2.
y_axis = norm.pdf(x_axis,0,2)

p.line(x_axis, y_axis, line_dash='solid', line_width=2)

cutoff = Span(location=1,
              dimension='height', line_color='green',
              line_dash='dashed', line_width=2)
p.add_layout(cutoff)

show(p, notebook_handle=True)

def update(new_cutoff_location):
    cutoff.location = new_cutoff_location
    push_notebook()
interact(update, new_cutoff_location = 1.0)
```

When I run this code I get `ValueError: PATCH-DOC message requires at least one event` at `push_notebook()`. I suspect this indicates that the update to `cutoff.location` isn't getting detected, so it it looks as if there are no changes to send. Passing the handle doesn't seem to make a difference. Looking at the sample code in [this github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3993), it looks like there used to be an `set` method on span elements, but there doesn't appear to be one on my span element `cutoff`. Maybe there is a different function I am supposed to call to register the change?

I'm on bokeh 0.12.11 with jupyter 1.0.0, jupyter-client 5.1.0, jupyter-console 5.2.0, jupyter-core 4.4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a regression in Bokeh `0.12.11`. Your code works with version `0.12.10` so the immediate workaround is to downgrade. I've made [GitHub issue here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/7268) that you can follow. We will issue a new point release with a fix ASAP.

UPDATE: The issue is now fixed in recent versions of Bokeh

Comment: I still have the issue under bokeh==0.12.10. Maybe a dependency change broke this? It might make sense for me to wait for 0.12.12 and test that.

Comment: I can't say. I ran your code with `0.12.10` and it functioned as expected.