# How can the `_property_values` of an element of a bokeh `figure.renderers` be changed directly?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, updates, ipywidgets

How can the `_property_values` of an element of a bokeh `figure.renderers` be changed directly? I learned that the lements of `renderers` have an id, so I expect to do something like `renderers['12345']`. But as it is a list (a PropertyValueList to be more precise), this doesn't work. Instead, the only solution I found is to iterate over the list, storing the correct element in a new pointer (?), modifying the pointer and thus modifying the original element.

Here is my toy example where a vertical line in a histogram is updated based on some widget's value:

```
import hvplot.pandas
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure

%matplotlib inline

hist, edges = np.histogram([1, 2, 2])

p = figure()
r = p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:])
vline = Span(location=0, dimension='height')
p.renderers.extend([vline])

def update_hist(x):    
    myspan = [x for x in p.renderers if x.id==vline.id][0]
    myspan._property_values['location'] = x
    show(p, notebook_handle=True)

widgets.interact(update_hist, x = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1, max=2))
```

Comment: You absolutely 100% should never touch `_property_values` directly. What is it you are actually trying to accomplish, described at a high level?

Comment: I want to plot the distribution of a variable (say income in a company) and by a widget, a specific employee can be selected. By a vertical line, the income of that employee should be shown. Did this answer your question @bigreddot? PS: at first, I extended p.renderers with multiple vertical lines, but I want to have only *one*. So I either have to delete the old one and create a new one, or to modify the old one, right?

Comment: No, the other option (and the best one, usually), is to update the data source for the glyph. See the examples in the repo https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/howto/notebook_comms for how to update the data source for an existing glyph without adding or removing.

Comment: @bigreddot thanks for pointing me into the right direction. For my understanding: `quad` is a glyph, but `span` is something different (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs.html), right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bigreddot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3406693/bigreddot) pointed me into the right direction: I don't have to update `p` directly, but the elements used to generate `p` (here the `Span`). By this I found the  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47583601/update-a-bokeh-span-with-an-interact-element-in-jupyter-notebook) where the code bears the solution: update `vline.location`.

Full code:

```
import hvplot.pandas
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import push_notebook, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.models import Span
from bokeh.plotting import figure

%matplotlib inline

hist, edges = np.histogram([1, 2, 2])

p = figure()
r = p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:])
vline = Span(location=0, dimension='height')
p.renderers.extend([vline])
show(p, notebook_handle=True)

def update_hist(x):    
    vline.location = x
    push_notebook()

widgets.interact(update_hist, x = widgets.FloatSlider(min=1, max=2, step = 0.01))
```

---

As a Python beginner, I still often oversee, that [Python does not have variables](https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/). So we can change an element `x` by changing `y`.

```
x = ['alice']
y = x
y[0] = 'bob'
x  # is now ['bob] too
```